# Code Not Working Properly - Trying To Create A Simple Graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphing

I'm trying to create a simple program where my inputs about data relating to daily COVID-19 cases will then be tabulated and created into a small graph. For example, I'll first input (primary input) will be: 7 20200401 20200403, which represents the # of inputs after my primary input, and from what dates the cases are from. Then I'll go onto input which the hospital, the # of cases from that hospital, and the day of the report. The number of cases per day will be represented by a * . When I go to run my program, it just shows me what the last # of cases inputted was for all 7 days. Is there any way to fix it, and have the program properly display the correct amount of cases per day?

Just to help you understand, here is what a sample input and output should be for this program:

Input:

```
7 20200401 20200403
HP1 20200401 1
HP2 20200401 1
HP3 20200401 1
HP4 20200402 1
HP5 20200402 1
HP6 20200403 1
HP7 20200403 1
```

Output:

```
20200401:***
20200402:**
20200403:**
```

But instead, I get this:

```
20200401:*
20200402:*
20200403:*
```

Here is my code:

```
CoronaCaseNumber = input("")
CoronaList = CoronaCaseNumber.split(" ")
LuckyNumber = CoronaList[0]
Date = CoronaList[1]
Date2 = CoronaList[2]
LuckyNumero = int(LuckyNumber)
DateList = []
CaseNumberList = []
for case in range(LuckyNumero):
    CoronaCaseData = input()
    CoronaList2 = CoronaCaseData.split(" ")
    InfoDate = CoronaList2[1]
    DateList.append(InfoDate)
    CaseNumber = CoronaList2[2]
    CaseNumberList.append(CaseNumber)

EmptySet = []
for i in DateList:
    if i >= Date and i <= Date2:
        if i not in EmptySet:
            EmptySet.append(i)

for i in range(0, len(CaseNumberList)):
    CaseNumberList[i] = int(CaseNumberList[i])

EmptySet.sort()
for i in range(len(EmptySet)):
    print("{}{}{}".format(EmptySet[i], ":", "*" * CaseNumberList[i]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm way too lazy to type in all that data everytime I run your script, so I automated that part to make development and testing of it easier. Likewise, I think the easiest thing to do would be to use the `collections` module's [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) class to keep track of what dates have been seen *and* the total number of cases seen on each of them. Here's what I mean:

```
from collections import defaultdict

#CoronaCaseNumber = input("")
#CoronaList = CoronaCaseNumber.split(" ")
#LuckyNumber = CoronaList[0]
#Date = CoronaList[1]
#Date2 = CoronaList[2]
LuckyNumber, Date, Date2 = "8 20200401 20200404".split(" ")

data = """\
HP4 20200402 1
HP5 20200402 1
HP1 20200401 1
HP2 20200401 1
HP3 20200401 1
HP6 20200403 0
HP6 20200404 1
HP7 20200404 1
""".splitlines()

LuckyNumero = int(LuckyNumber)
DateList = []
CaseNumberList = []
for case in range(LuckyNumero):
    CoronaCaseData = data[case]
    CoronaList2 = CoronaCaseData.split(" ")
    InfoDate = CoronaList2[1]
    DateList.append(InfoDate)
    CaseNumber = CoronaList2[2]
    CaseNumberList.append(CaseNumber)

DailyCases = defaultdict(int)

for i, d in enumerate(DateList):
    if Date <= d <= Date2:  # Valid date?
        DailyCases[d] += int(CaseNumberList[i])

# Print daily cases sorted by date (i.e. the dictionary's keys).
for date in sorted(DailyCases, key=lambda d: int(d)):
    print("{}:{}".format(date, '*' * DailyCases[date]))
```

Output:

```
20200401:***
20200402:**
20200403:
20200404:**
```

Comment: Though the code does work, it does not sort the dates like it used to now, and at times, doesn't display the dates if there are no cases on those dates. Is there a way to overcome that?

Comment: I modified my answer to sort the data by date. It _will_ print dates with no cases — as the sample output shows — but only if an entry indicating that was input. You will need to do something else if you want something printed for dates with no entries.